# How can we connect spark structured stream to redis?

Tags: redis, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

My goal is to ingest streaming data from redis and process. How can I connect and process data via spark structured streaming ?

Comment: https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read data from Redis Streams in Spark, we need to establish how to connect to Redis, as well as the schema structure of the data in Redis Streams.

To connect to Redis, we must create a new SparkSession with connection parameters for Redis:

```
import com.redislabs.provider.redis._
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis

object Samj45 {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
         val spark = SparkSession
                     .builder()
                     .appName("redis-example")
                     .master("local[*]")
                     .config("spark.redis.host", "localhost")
                     .config("spark.redis.port", "6379")
                     .getOrCreate()

         val data_from_redis = spark
                     .readStream
                     .format("redis")
                     .option("stream.keys","data_clicks")
                     .schema(StructType(Array(
                           StructField("asset", StringType),
                           StructField("cost", LongType)
                      )))
                      .load()
```

And for writing you can use a ForeachWriter. Let me know if this helps.